# What is the magic for placing breakpoints for the Node debugger?

Tags: visual-studio-code

On Ubuntu 15.4 and they worked once after a few reinstalls and now I just can't place them. Using the latest version.

Comment: This can be very sensitive to the node version you are using, what is it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you file an issue over at GH and indicate which node version you are on: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues

Whenever there is a new node.js version, our debugger might need to adopt new semantics. It could be that we are not yet supporting node.js 5.0.